# Accessing Bootstrap Modal Pop on Master Page from Child Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have Modal pop Pop on Master Page 
Supposse like this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to access this modal pop from Chil Page 
What I have done until is on button Click

```
     HtmlGenericControl loginDIV =(HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("login");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Master.Page,      Master.Page.GetType(), $"LoginModel", $"$('#{loginDIV}').modal();", true);
```

And

```
HtmlGenericControl loginDIV =(HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("login");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), $"LoginModel", $"$('#{loginDIV}').modal();", true);
```

I dont know the other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

You should have the following code on your master page for the modal pop up

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

and on the child page

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

make sure the `data-target` has the same id as the modal div, in this case `myModal`

Comment: I want to access this from Code behind